# NavigationStack with separate history for each tab

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make it so that each of my tabs has a separate navigation stack so that each one can navigate independently. Here's what my tab view looks like

```
TabView {
    RouterView {
        HomeView()
    }
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "house.fill")
            Text("Home")
        }
        .tag(1)
    RouterView {
        SearchView()
    }
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
            Text("Search")
        }
        .tag(2)
    NewTripView()
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "plus.app")
            Text("Add Trip")
        }
        .tag(3)
    RouterView {
        CalendarTabView()
    }
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "calendar")
            Text("Shared Calendar")
        }
        .tag(4)
    RouterView {
        ProfileView()
    }
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "person")
            Text("Me")
        }
        .tag(5)

}
```

So each tab view is wrapped in a RouterView, which I have created, it looks like this:

```
struct RouterView <Content: View>: View {
    @StateObject var router = Router.router
    var content: () -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $router.history) {
            content()
            .navigationDestination(for: Route.self) { route in
                Router.handle(route)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This view uses a Router observed object:

```
class Router: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var history: [Route] = []
    static let router: Router = Router()

    static func navigate(_ route: Route) {
        router.history.append(route)
    }

    static func handle(_ route: Route) -> some View {
        switch route {
        case .something:
            return SomeView()
        }
    }
}

enum Route: Hashable {
    case something
}
```

This to me seems like it would create a new `Router` instance for each tab, but it seems to share history across them. For example, if I navigate to a subview using `.handle` on one tab, then switch to another tab, that subview is already present on the new tab, even though that tab should have a totally separate history. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in your Router

```
static let router: Router = Router()
```

Is what is called a “Singleton” which essentially means one instance for everything.

Just change

```
 @StateObject var router = Router.router
```

To

```
  @StateObject var router = Router()
```

Now each `StateObject` will preserve its own instance as designed.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, that's what I was thinking. The issue of course, is now the above `navigate` method doesn't work, because they are using different instances of the router, right? Any thoughts with how to deal with this?

Comment: My only thought is to have a global state for each tab navigation path history but that seems pretty messy.

Comment: @goddamnyouryan the navigate will work for each tab just remove the static too.

Comment: @goddamnyouryan if I answered your question do you mind accepting the answer (green checkmark) and maybe upvoting?

Comment: sure! But removing the `static` from the navigate method didn't work, because you then get the error: `Static member 'router' cannot be used on instance of type 'Router'`. if i change `router` to `self` then when I try to use `Router.navigate(.aPath)` i get `Instance member 'navigate' cannot be used on type 'Router'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?`. Should i maybe store the instance of the router as an environment variable and use it like `router.navigate(.whatever)` instead?

Comment: @goddamnyouryan yes, that is the only way to have “different instances” static == single instance.